# How do I prove that $|x+y| \ge \big||x|-|y|\big|$?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I don't know where to start with proving this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now that the post has been edited, try to get rid off the absolute value around $\vert x\vert -\vert y\vert$.

Comment: Hint: $x=x-y+y$ and $y=y-x+x$. Apply the triangle inequality to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $|x+y| \geq ||x|-|y||$ is the same as to prove two separate inequalities: $|x+y| \geq |x| - |y|$ and $|x+y| \geq |y| - |x|$. Each of these two can be proved easily using the standard triangle inequality.