# Is it true that $|x + y| \geq |x| - |y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, triangle-inequality

Is the above inequality true? I feel that it is, but I am having a tough time convincing myself (or coming up with an appropriate counter-example).

Comment: $|x|=|x+y-y|\le|x+y|+|y|$ by the triangle inequality

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/696581/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x|=|x+y-y|\le|x+y|+|y|$ by the triangle inequality.